# Are hot liquids better for digestion?

Tags: digestion, water, liquids

Intuitively, I think cold liquids require energy to move them up to a temperature more suitable for the body. Since hot liquids are closer to our bodies' core temperatures, I figure it's easier for the body to digest hot liquids.  Is there any evidence to support this? I'm wondering specifically about water, but discussion of other liquids would be nice.

Comment: I didn't write a full answer, but researching this I found this paper on the temperature of coffee when it reaches the stomach http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1411981/?page=1 it's just kind of awesome :-)